# Use of undeclared type 'GIDSignInUIDelegate' when changing GoogleSignIn pod version

Tags: swift, xcode, google-signin

Problem when changing pod version of GoogleSignIn from previous versions to v5.0.0.

Comment: welcome to stack, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to change `GIDSignInUIDelegate` to `GIDSignInDelegate` as the example in GoogleSignIn documentation:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift

Answer (score 9):

The `GIDSignInUIDelegate` protocol used to be necessary to be implemented in the UIViewController which initiated `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()`. That UIViewController had to register itself using the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self`.

Since the GoogleSignIn 5.0.0 this has changed. The UIViewController which initiates the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()` should register itself using the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self` and apparently no longer needs to implement the `GIDSignInUIDelegate` which no longer exists.

The `GIDSignInDelegate` is still intended to be implemented typically in the AppDelegate which should register itself using `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self`.

Please see also: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `GIDSignInUIDelegate`, check this link for migration guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide#migrating_from_versions_prior_to_v500

Just use `GIDSignInDelegate` and replace `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self` with `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self` and

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
    sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
    annotation: annotation)
```

with `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)`

This was where my app was getting rejected for `UIWebView`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self and GIDSignInUIDelegate protocol.  Use GIDSignInDelegate protocol only and import GoogleUtilities .Implement sigin method.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleUtilities

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate  {
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        
    }
    

    
    @IBAction func googleSignIn(sender: AnyObject) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
    
    
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        print("Google Sing In didSignInForUser")
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication.idToken)!, accessToken: (authentication.accessToken)!)// When user is signed in
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }    })  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using latest google singing sdk use this code on button action

```
 let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: KGoogle.clientID)

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let user = user else { return }

    if let profiledata = user.profile {
        
        let userId : String = user.userID ?? ""
        let givenName : String = profiledata.givenName ?? ""
        let familyName : String = profiledata.familyName ?? ""
        let email : String = profiledata.email
        
        if let imgurl = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 100) {
            let absoluteurl : String = imgurl.absoluteString
            //HERE CALL YOUR SERVER API
        }
    }
    
}
```